# Choosing a database for reverse auction marketplace

Tags: web-apps, software-development, database, web-services, mobile

I'm building a reverse bidding marketplace for high-end goods in which vendors will bid against each other (without knowing the each other's price) to drive the price down for consumers. I'm a product guy with only nominal development experience so I'm wondering from a technical standpoint:

If I should be considering a mobile-first or web-based architecture to start?

Should I be choosing my database infrastructure with the assumption that I'll have to Scale? If so, would a NoSQL database like Riak or Cassandra make sense? If I should be starting with something like MySQL, would it cost me more in the long run if I have to migrate to NoSQL vs. implementing Riak or Cassandra from Day 1?

I've been reading that most view Riak as the top choice when it comes to scalability; is this accurate?

Comment: Robby, this site is about "recommending software for specific requirements" – not about "figuring out specific requirements". So I'm sorry to tell you this question is off-topic here. It would rather require a discussion, and thus is much better fit in a discussion forum than on a Q&A site.

Answer (score 2):

I would talk with your developer about what he's most comfortable with. In general, an experienced developer can build caching layers to handle scale (supposedly all tweets go through MySQL). If you want to develop a MVP, I'd probably suggest Rails with Postgres on Heroku.

The strongest use case for something like Cassandra is capturing information like logs and not relational.